# Logistic Regression Cost Function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)
data = load('ex2data1.txt');

y = data(:, 3);

theta = [1;1;2];
m = length(y); 
one = ones(m,1);
X1 = data(:, [1, 2]);
X =  [one X1];

J = 0;
grad = zeros(size(theta));

J= 1/m *((sum(-y*log(sigmoid(X*theta)))) - (sum(1-y * log(1 - sigmoid(X*theta)))));

for i = 1:m 
grad = (1/m) * sum (sigmoid(X*theta) - y')*X;
end

end
```

I want to know if i implemented the cost function and gradient descent correctly i am getting NaN answer though this and does theta(1) always have to be 0 i have it as 1 here. How many iterations i need for grad that should be equal to the length of matrix or something else?

Comment: You missed a bracket in J, `1-y` should be `(1-y)`. Also, your code does not every update theta with the grad computed. Finally - number of iterations is a hyperparameter which does not have one magical value, for debugging just set it to a big value (say 1000)

Comment: To update theta i would have to do this ?
`theta = theta - (alpha * grad);`

Comment: yes, this is a typical gradient update

Answer (score 2):

```
function [J, grad] = costFunction(theta, X, y)

m = length(y);

J = 0;
grad = zeros(size(theta));

sig = 1./(1 + (exp(-(X * theta))));
J = ((-y' * log(sig)) - ((1 - y)' * log(1 - sig)))/m;
grad = ((sig - y)' * X)/m;

end
```

where

> sig = 1./(1 + (exp(-(X * theta))));

is matrix representation of the logistic regression hypothesis which is deﬁned as:

[image]

where function g is the sigmoid function. The sigmoid function is deﬁned as:

[image]

> J = ((-y' * log(sig)) - ((1 - y)' * log(1 - sig)))/m;

is matrix representation of the cost function in logistic regression :

[image]

and

> grad = ((sig - y)' * X)/m;

is matrix representation of the gradient of the cost which is a vector of the same length as θ where the jth element (for j = 0,1,...,n) is deﬁned as follows:

[image]